# Hide the first dropdown selected text from second dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

I need to change the based on the text, not value because values are different. So can please anyone help me.

```
$("#primary_supplier").change(function () {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(this).text();
    var optionValues = [];
    $('#secondary_supplier option').each(function () {
        optionValues.push($(this).text());
    });
    optionValues.toString();
    console.log(optionValues);
    if ($.inArray(selectedText, optionValues) != '-1') {
        var others = $("#secondary_supplier option[value=" + selectedText + "]");
        $("#secondary_supplier option[selectedText]").css("display", "none");
        $("#secondary_supplier :not(option[value=" + selectedText + "])").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Change what?

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly. It is really difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have two dropdowns different values and the same text. if the select first drop-down text that text removes in the second dropdown. it is not based on the values because values are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```js
$(function() {
    $("#primary_supplier").change(function() {
        loadSecondDropdown(this);
    });
    
});
function loadSecondDropdown(ele){
  var sele=$('option:selected', ele).text();
  $("#secondary_supplier").val('default');      
  $('#secondary_supplier option').show();
  $('#secondary_supplier option').each(function () {           
    if(sele==$(this).text()){
      $(this).hide();
    }           
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Primary
</label>
<select id="primary_supplier" name="projectKey">    
    <option value="default">--select--</option>
    <option value="p1">supplier 1</option>
    <option value="p2">supplier 2</option>
    <option value="p3">supplier 3</option>
    <option value="p4">supplier 4</option>
</select>
<label>Secondary
</label>
<select id="secondary_supplier" name="projectKey">
    <option value="default">--select--</option>
    <option value="s1">supplier 1</option>
    <option value="s2">supplier 2</option>
    <option value="s3">supplier 3</option>
    <option value="s4">supplier 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @venkataprasad , is that you looking for?